# Rewriting the HAVING clause and COUNT function

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, url-rewriting, having

I'm trying to conceptually understand how to rewrite the HAVING clause and COUNT function.

I was asked "Find the names of all reviewers who have contributed three or more ratings. (As an extra challenge, try writing the query without HAVING or without COUNT.)" in relation this this simple database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/35779/2/0

The query with HAVING and COUNT is easy. Without, I'm having difficulty.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Including the sample data rather than a link would be helpful, setting up a fiddle would be even better: sqlfiddle.com
Showing what you've tried so far would be good too, and you should indicate what database you are working with, as solutions can vary between them.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/35779/2/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `SUM(1)` in place of `COUNT` in a subquery, and using `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM (SELECT rID,SUM(1) Sum1
      FROM rating
      GROUP BY rID
      )a
JOIN reviewer b
  ON a.rID = b.rID
WHERE Sum1 >= 3
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7ab3a/1/0)

Update: Some explanation of `SUM(1)`:
Adding a constant to a `SELECT` statement will result in that value being repeated for every row returned, for example:

```
SELECT rID
      ,1 as Col1
FROM rating
```

Returns:

```
| rID | Col1 |
|-----|------|
| 201 |    1 |
| 201 |    1 |
| 202 |    1 |
| 203 |    1 |
| 203 |    1 |
......
```

`SUM(1)` is applying a constant `1` to every row and aggregating it.

Comment: Could you please explain what SUM(1) is the sum of?

Comment: Think of a column populated with nothing but `1` for every row, adding all those 1's together gets you the equivalent of `COUNT` without using `COUNT`.  Not something you'd do in practice, but it meets the requirement of avoiding `COUNT`.